How to add auto increment primary column with jOOQ
In MySQL/MariaDB I tried to do something like:
ctx.alterTable("my_table")
   .addColumn("id", SQLDataType.BIGINT.identity(true))
   .execute();
ctx.alterTable("my_table")
   .add(DSL.primaryKey("id"))
   .execute();

But the first step fails because auto increment column must be a key. Is there a clean way to do this that I missed, or should I just do something like .getSql() + " primary key"?

When MySQL says "KEY" here, it doesn't mean "PRIMARY KEY", it really means "index". You'll need to use Jooq to add the column and add it to an INDEX ("KEY" in MySQL parlance) in a single DDL txn - I'll admit I don't know Jooq well enough to know how to do that without using manual SQL.

@Dai I know, but how does that change anything? I want it to be PK in the end. Is there a way to add auto increment column with index using jOOQ in one statement?

yeah, exactly, I will just wait for Lukas to answer :D

Oh, sorry, I misunderstood you; I thought you didn't want to make it a PK column. I don't recommend using ALTER TABLE to change a PK - I think you should create a new empty table with the new design, then copy the data over and DROP the original.

That sounds reasonable, but in our setup it would complicate things quite a bit. We will probably end up adding " primary key" to the sql before executing it

Try doing a single ALTER with both changes at the same time.

@RickJames Of course, that's what the question was about. Lukas already answered it.

You can add multiple things with the ALTER TABLE statement, if your RDBMS supports that:
ctx.alterTable("my_table")
   .add(
        field("id", SQLDataType.BIGINT.identity(true)),
        constraint("pk").primaryKey("id"))
   .execute();

